# Google Places Android Autocomplete: can I remove the country from the place name?

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-location

I am using Google's Place Api for getting a list of places from the string searched from a end user. But i want to remove the country name from the suggestion coming as well as from list of responses for a address.

how can i achieve this in android  ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have Code like below. What ever you don't need just remove it.

```
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
```

Answer (score -1):

You appears to be using the Javascript version of the Google Places API.  Let me know if I've guessed incorrectly!

All you need to do is add `&region=US` when you load the Google Maps API.  E.g.:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&region=US">
```

Note that this will still show the country for Autocomplete predictions outside of the United States (which helps disambiguate "Paris, TX" from "Paris, France").

See the section on [Region localization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#Region) in the Google Maps APIs documentation for more details on this parameter.

If you need even more control over the appearance, you can use the [`AutocompleteService` programmatic API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) to build your own UI, rather than using the `Autocomplete` control.

Comment: No, I am using place api's android version !!  and Secondly i want to remove the country name from suggestion as well as result list.

Comment: Ah, I got the wrong idea from your image.  In that case I think your only option currently is to use the programmatic API (GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions) rather than the pre-built widgets, so you can adjust the results before showing them to the user.  But that's obviously going to be a lot more work, sorry :(

Comment: ok tnx, that means i need to manage the results and process them and then show ..